# VB.net formatting series and removing 1 legend entry

Tags: excel, vb.net, charts, legend, series

I've got some VB.NET code which uses Excel to create a chart from some data. The chart works how it should but I'm finding the switch from VBA to VB formatting-wise difficult.

I want just series 1 in the legend to be deleted and the data in the chart itself to either have transparency set to 100 or to have fill set to no fill. I've played with `charpage.seriescollection(1).format.fill` etc. but I'm not getting it.

My code:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkbooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

    Dim chartPage As Excel.Chart
    Dim xlCharts As Excel.ChartObjects
    Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim chartRange As Excel.Range
    Dim Chartarea As Excel.ChartArea

xlCharts = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
        myChart = xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 900, 500)
        chartPage = myChart.Chart
        chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("B1", "E2000")
        chartPage.SetSourceData(Source:=chartRange)
        chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlBarStacked
        chartPage.ChartWizard(Title:="Gantt Chart of Offshore Operations")
        chartPage.Legend.Position = Excel.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionTop

        'Y axis
        With chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory)
            .categorytype = Excel.XlCategoryType.xlTimeScale
            .BaseUnit = Excel.XlTimeUnit.xlDays
        End With

        'X axis
        With chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue)
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Caption = "Time (Days)"
        End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up some data in Excel, saved it, and used the following code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

    Sub X()
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing

        Try
            xlApp = New Excel.Application()
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\Book1.xlsx")
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

            Dim xlCharts As Excel.ChartObjects = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
            Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject = xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 900, 500)
            Dim chartPage As Excel.Chart = myChart.Chart
            Dim chartRange As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("B1", "E20")

            chartPage.SetSourceData(Source:=chartRange)
            chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlBarStacked
            chartPage.ChartWizard(Title:="Gantt Chart of Offshore Operations")

            ' *****************
            myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ""
            myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.ColorIndex = Excel.Constants.xlNone

            chartPage.Legend.Position = Excel.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionTop

            'Y axis
            With chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory)
                .categorytype = Excel.XlCategoryType.xlTimeScale
                .BaseUnit = Excel.XlTimeUnit.xlDays
            End With

            'X axis
            With chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue)
                .HasTitle = True
                .AxisTitle.Caption = "Time (Days)"
            End With

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\temp\Book2")

        Finally
            xlWorkBook.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()

        End Try

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            X()
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Which generated this:

[image]

Which I *think* is what you wanted.

Credits:

- [How to use VBA to make a cell in Excel 2007 transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9116948/1115360)
- [Excel constants enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.constants.aspx)

Comment: Dude! That's exactly what I was after. Thank you. I've been struggling a bit with the correct commands. Where do you go to mainly get commands for things you don't know? I've been looking on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489216.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 but as I don't have chart1 assigned it doesn't work